# call to insert a table in html by python FASTAPI

Tags: python, html, pandas, fastapi

Background: I'm new to html and fastAPI and not sure about the right terminology for the questions I have. I know how to insert a image in html by doing following:

```
<img scr="create_image" alt="">
```

and then on python side I can write something like below to create and insert the image

```
@app.route("/create_image")
def image():
   # create a image
   return image
```

Question: I'm trying to do something similar for insert a table into html but not sure what code to write on the html end, but something similar like below

```
<table scr="create_table" alt=""> # its definitely wrong, but this is the idea.
```

on the python side, I'm planning to do following:

```
@app.route("/create_table")
def table():
   df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2],"col2":[3,4]})
   return df.to_html()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code in html file will serve the purpose

```
<iframe src="create_table"></iframe>
```